# Illegal string offset 'formId' in repeater gravityform

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater

PLease Help me,
I have this errors

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'formId' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\repeater-add-on-for-gravity-forms\class-gf-field-repeater.php
>   on line 287
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'children' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\repeater-add-on-for-gravity-forms\class-gf-field-repeater.php
>   on line 291

```
...

if (empty($value)) {
    $value['formId'] = $form_id;
    if (!empty($repeater_start)) { $value['start'] = $repeater_start; }
        if (!empty($repeater_min)) { $value['min'] = $repeater_min; }
        if (!empty($repeater_max)) { $value['max'] = $repeater_max; }
        if (!empty($repeater_children)) { $value['children'] = $repeater_children; }

        $value = json_encode($value);
    }

...
```

Comment: How is $value set - should be something like `$value=[];` prior to this code.

Comment: I copy the code from source file

Comment: The error is that $value may be just a string and you are trying to use it as an array.  So can you find out where $value is before the code above?

Comment: could u plz help me. Here is full code.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I solved adding `$value = array()` in line 287.

```js
if (empty($value)) {
    $value = array();
    $value['formId'] = $form_id;
    if (!empty($repeater_start)) { $value['start'] = $repeater_start; }
    if (!empty($repeater_min)) { $value['min'] = $repeater_min; }
    if (!empty($repeater_max)) { $value['max'] = $repeater_max; }
    if (!empty($repeater_children)) { $value['children'] = $repeater_children; }
    $value = json_encode($value);
}
```

That's work for me, I hope it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class GF_Field_Repeater extends GF_Field {
    public $type = 'repeater';

    public static function init_admin() {
        $admin_page = rgget('page');

        if ($admin_page == 'gf_edit_forms' && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
            add_action('gform_field_standard_settings' , array('GF_Field_Repeater', 'gform_standard_settings'), 10, 2);
            add_action('gform_field_appearance_settings' , array('GF_Field_Repeater', 'gform_appearance_settings'), 10, 2);
            add_action('gform_editor_js_set_default_values', array('GF_Field_Repeater', 'gform_set_defaults'));
            add_action('gform_editor_js', array('GF_Field_Repeater', 'gform_editor'));
            add_filter('gform_tooltips', array('GF_Field_Repeater', 'gform_tooltips'));
        }

        if ($admin_page == 'gf_entries') {
            add_filter('gform_form_post_get_meta', array('GF_Field_Repeater', 'gform_hide_children'));
        }
    }

    public static function init_frontend() {
        add_action('gform_form_args', array('GF_Field_Repeater', 'gform_disable_ajax'));
        add_action('gform_enqueue_scripts', array('GF_Field_Repeater', 'gform_enqueue_scripts'), 10, 2);
        add_filter('gform_pre_render', array('GF_Field_Repeater', 'gform_unhide_children_validation'));
        add_filter('gform_pre_validation', array('GF_Field_Repeater', 'gform_bypass_children_validation'));
    }

    public static function gform_enqueue_scripts($form, $is_ajax) {
        if (!empty($form)) {
            if (GF_Field_Repeater::get_field_index($form) !== false) {
                wp_enqueue_script('gforms_repeater_postcapture_js', plugins_url('js/jquery.postcapture.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '0.0.1');
                wp_enqueue_script('gforms_repeater_js', plugins_url('js/gf-repeater.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), GF_REPEATER_VERSION);
                wp_enqueue_style('gforms_repeater_css', plugins_url('css/gf-repeater.css', __FILE__), array(), GF_REPEATER_VERSION);
            }
        }
    }

    public function get_form_editor_field_title() {
        return 'Repeater';
    }

    public function get_form_editor_field_settings() {
        return array(
            'admin_label_setting',
            'css_class_setting',
            'description_setting',
            'error_message_setting',
            'label_setting',
            'prepopulate_field_setting'
        );
    }

    public static function gform_set_defaults() {
        echo "
            case \"repeater\" :
                field.label = \"Repeater\";
            break;
        ";
    }

    public static function gform_standard_settings($position, $form_id) {
        if ($position == 1600) {
            echo "<li class=\"repeater_settings field_setting\">
                    <label for=\"field_repeater_start\">Start ";

            gform_tooltip('form_field_repeater_start');

            echo "  </label>
                    <input type=\"number\" id=\"field_repeater_start\" min=\"1\" value=\"1\" onchange=\"SetFieldProperty('start', this.value);\">
                </li>";

            echo "<li class=\"repeater_settings field_setting\">
                    <label for=\"field_repeater_min\">Min ";

            gform_tooltip('form_field_repeater_min');

            echo "  </label>
                    <input type=\"number\" id=\"field_repeater_min\" min=\"1\" value=\"1\" onchange=\"SetFieldProperty('min', this.value);\">
                </li>";

            echo "<li class=\"repeater_settings field_setting\">
                    <label for=\"field_repeater_max\">Max ";

            gform_tooltip('form_field_repeater_max');

            echo "  </label>
                    <input type=\"number\" id=\"field_repeater_max\" min=\"1\" onchange=\"SetFieldProperty('max', this.value);\">
                </li>";
        }
    }

    public static function gform_appearance_settings($position, $form_id) {
        if ($position == 400) {
            echo "<li class=\"repeater_settings field_setting\">
                    <input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"field_repeater_hideLabel\" onchange=\"SetFieldProperty('hideLabel', this.checked);\"> 
                    <label for=\"field_repeater_hideLabel\" class=\"inline\">Hide Label & Description ";

            gform_tooltip('form_field_repeater_hideLabel');

            echo "  </label>
                </li>";
        }
    }

    public static function gform_editor() {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                fieldSettings['repeater'] += ', .repeater_settings';
                jQuery(document).bind('gform_load_field_settings', function(event, field, form){
                    jQuery('#field_repeater_start').val(field['start']);
                    jQuery('#field_repeater_min').val(field['min']);
                    jQuery('#field_repeater_max').val(field['max']);
                    jQuery('#field_repeater_hideLabel').prop('checked', field['hideLabel']);
                });
            </script>";
    }

    public static function gform_tooltips($tooltips) {
        $tooltips['form_field_repeater_start'] = "The number of times the repeater will be repeated when the form is rendered. Leaving this field blank or setting it to a number higher than the maximum number is the same as setting it to 1.";
        $tooltips['form_field_repeater_min'] = "The minimum number of times the repeater is allowed to be repeated. Leaving this field blank or setting it to a number higher than the maximum field is the same as setting it to 1.";
        $tooltips['form_field_repeater_max'] = "The maximum number of times the repeater is allowed to be repeated. Leaving this field blank or setting it to a number lower than the minimum field is the same as setting it to unlimited.";
        $tooltips['form_field_repeater_hideLabel'] = "If this is checked, the repeater label and description will not be shown to users on the form.";
        return $tooltips;
    }

    function validate($value, $form) {
        $repeater_required = $this->repeaterRequiredChildren;

        if (!empty($repeater_required)) {
            $dataArray = json_decode($value, true);

            foreach ($form['fields'] as $key=>$value) {
                $fieldKeys[$value['id']] = $key;

                if (is_array($value['inputs'])) {
                    foreach ($value['inputs'] as $inputKey=>$inputValue) {
                        $inputKeys[$value['id']][$inputValue['id']] = $inputKey;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($dataArray['repeatCount'] < $this->min) {
                $this->failed_validation  = true;
                $this->validation_message = "A minimum number of ".$this->min." is required.";
                return;
            }

            if ($this->max && $dataArray['repeatCount'] > $this->max) {
                $this->failed_validation  = true;
                $this->validation_message = "A maximum number of ".$this->max." is allowed.";
                return;
            }

            for ($i = 1; $i < $dataArray['repeatCount'] + 1; $i++) {
                foreach ($dataArray['children'] as $field_id=>$field) {
                    $inputNames = $field['inputs'];
                    $repeatSkips = $field['conditionalLogic']['skip'];

                    if (!is_array($inputNames)) { continue; }

                    if (is_array($repeatSkips)) {
                        if (in_array($i, $repeatSkips) || in_array('all', $repeatSkips)) { continue; }
                    }

                    foreach ($inputNames as $inputName) {
                        if (is_array($inputName)) { $inputName = reset($inputName); }

                        if (substr($inputName, -2) == '[]') {
                            $getInputName = substr($inputName, 0, strlen($inputName) - 2).'-'.$dataArray['repeaterId'].'-'.$i;
                        } else {
                            $getInputName = $inputName.'-'.$dataArray['repeaterId'].'-'.$i;
                        }

                        $getInputName = str_replace('.', '_', strval($getInputName));
                        $getInputData = rgpost($getInputName);
                        $getInputIdNum = preg_split("/(_|-)/", $getInputName);

                        if (in_array($getInputIdNum[1], $repeater_required)) {
                            $fieldKey = $fieldKeys[$getInputIdNum[1]];
                            $fieldType = $form['fields'][$fieldKey]['type'];
                            $failedValidation = false;

                            switch($fieldType) {
                                case 'name':
                                    $requiredIDs = array(3, 6);
                                    if (in_array($getInputIdNum[2], $requiredIDs) && empty($getInputData)) { $failedValidation = true; }
                                    break;
                                case 'address':
                                    $skipIDs = array(2);
                                    if (!in_array($getInputIdNum[2], $skipIDs) && empty($getInputData)) { $failedValidation = true; }
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    if (empty($getInputData)) { $failedValidation = true; }
                            }

                            if ($failedValidation) {
                                $this->failed_validation  = true;
                                if ($this->errorMessage) { $this->validation_message = $this->errorMessage; } else { $this->validation_message = "A required field was left blank."; }
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function get_field_content($value, $force_frontend_label, $form) {
        if (is_admin()) {
            $admin_buttons = $this->get_admin_buttons();
            $field_content = "{$admin_buttons}
                            <div class=\"gf-pagebreak-first gf-pagebreak-container gf-repeater gf-repeater-start\">
                                <div class=\"gf-pagebreak-text-before\">begin repeater</div>
                                <div class=\"gf-pagebreak-text-main\"><span>REPEATER</span></div>
                                <div class=\"gf-pagebreak-text-after\">top of repeater</div>
                            </div>";
        } else {
            $field_label        = $this->get_field_label($force_frontend_label, $value);
            $description        = $this->get_description($this->description, 'gsection_description gf_repeater_description');
            $hide_label         = $this->hideLabel;
            $validation_message = ( $this->failed_validation && ! empty( $this->validation_message ) ) ? sprintf( "<div class='gfield_description validation_message'>%s</div>", $this->validation_message ) : '';
            if (!empty($field_label)) { $field_label = "<h2 class='gf_repeater_title'>{$field_label}</h2>"; } else { $field_label = ''; }
            if ($hide_label) { $field_label = ''; $description = ''; }
            $field_content = "<div class=\"ginput_container ginput_container_repeater\">{$field_label}{FIELD}</div>{$description}{$validation_message}";
        }
        return $field_content;
    }

    public function get_field_input($form, $value = '', $entry = null) {
        if (is_admin()) {
            return '';
        } else {
            $form_id            = $form['id'];
            $is_entry_detail    = $this->is_entry_detail();
            $is_form_editor     = $this->is_form_editor();
            $id                 = (int) $this->id;
            $field_id           = $is_entry_detail || $is_form_editor || $form_id == 0 ? "input_$id" : 'input_' . $form_id . "_$id";
            $tabindex           = $this->get_tabindex();
            $repeater_parem     = $this->inputName;
            $repeater_start     = $this->start;
            $repeater_min       = $this->min;
            $repeater_max       = $this->max;
            $repeater_required  = $this->repeaterRequiredChildren;
            $repeater_children  = $this->repeaterChildren;

            if (!empty($repeater_parem)) {
                $repeater_parem_value = GFFormsModel::get_parameter_value($repeater_parem, $value, $this);
                if (!empty($repeater_parem_value)) { $repeater_start = $repeater_parem_value; }
            }

            if (!empty($repeater_children)) {
                $repeater_children_info = array();
                $repeater_parems = GF_Field_Repeater::get_children_parem_values($form, $repeater_children);

                foreach($repeater_children as $repeater_child) {
                    $repeater_children_info[$repeater_child] = array();
                    $repeater_child_field_index = GF_Field_Repeater::get_field_index($form, 'id', $repeater_child);

                    if (!empty($repeater_required)) {
                        if (in_array($repeater_child, $repeater_required)) {
                            $repeater_children_info[$repeater_child]['required'] = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!empty($repeater_parems)) {
                        if (array_key_exists($repeater_child, $repeater_parems)) {
                            $repeater_children_info[$repeater_child]['prePopulate'] = $repeater_parems[$repeater_child];
                        }
                    }

                    if ($repeater_child_field_index !== false) {
                        if ($form['fields'][$repeater_child_field_index]['inputMask']) {
                            $repeater_children_info[$repeater_child]['inputMask'] = $form['fields'][$repeater_child_field_index]['inputMaskValue'];
                        } elseif ($form['fields'][$repeater_child_field_index]['type'] == 'phone' && $form['fields'][$repeater_child_field_index]['phoneFormat'] = 'standard') {
                            $repeater_children_info[$repeater_child]['inputMask'] = "(999) 999-9999";
                        }

                        if ($form['fields'][$repeater_child_field_index]['conditionalLogic']) {
                            $repeater_children_info[$repeater_child]['conditionalLogic'] = $form['fields'][$repeater_child_field_index]['conditionalLogic'];
                        }
                    }
                }

                $repeater_children = $repeater_children_info;
            }

            if (empty($value)) {
                $value['formId'] = $form_id;
                if (!empty($repeater_start)) { $value['start'] = $repeater_start; }
                if (!empty($repeater_min)) { $value['min'] = $repeater_min; }
                if (!empty($repeater_max)) { $value['max'] = $repeater_max; }
                if (!empty($repeater_children)) { $value['children'] = $repeater_children; }

                $value = json_encode($value);
            }

            return sprintf("<input name='input_%d' id='%s' type='hidden' class='gform_repeater' value='%s' %s />", $id, $field_id, $value, $tabindex);
        }
    }

    public function get_value_save_entry($value, $form, $input_name, $lead_id, $lead) {
        $dataArray = json_decode($value, true);
        $value = Array();

        for ($i = 1; $i < $dataArray['repeatCount'] + 1; $i++) {
            foreach ($dataArray['children'] as $field_id=>$field) {
                $inputData = Array();

                if (array_key_exists('inputs', $field)) {
                    $inputNames = $field['inputs'];
                    $repeatSkips = $field['conditionalLogic']['skip'];

                    if (is_array($repeatSkips)) {
                        if (in_array($i, $repeatSkips) || in_array('all', $repeatSkips)) { continue; }
                    }

                    if (is_array($inputNames)) {
                        foreach ($inputNames as $inputName) {
                            if (substr($inputName, -2) == '[]') {
                                $getInputName = substr($inputName, 0, strlen($inputName) - 2).'-'.$dataArray['repeaterId'].'-'.$i;
                            } else {
                                $getInputName = $inputName.'-'.$dataArray['repeaterId'].'-'.$i;
                            }

                            $getInputData = rgpost(str_replace('.', '_', strval($getInputName)));

                            if (!empty($getInputData)) {
                                if (is_array($getInputData)) {
                                    foreach ($getInputData as $theInputData) {
                                        $inputData[] = $theInputData;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $inputData[] = $getInputData;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (GF_Field_Repeater::get_field_type($form, $field_id) == 'section') { $inputData = '[gfRepeater-section]'; }
                }

                $childValue[$field_id] = $inputData;
            }
            $value[$i] = $childValue;
        }

        return maybe_serialize($value);
    }

    public function get_value_entry_list($value, $entry, $field_id, $columns, $form) {
        if (empty($value)) {
            return '';
        } else {
            $dataArray = GFFormsModel::unserialize($value);
            $arrayCount = count($dataArray);
            if ($arrayCount > 1) { $returnText = $arrayCount.' entries'; } else { $returnText = $arrayCount.' entry'; }
            return $returnText;
        }
    }

    public function get_value_entry_detail($value, $currency = '', $use_text = false, $format = 'html', $media = 'screen') {
        if (empty($value)) {
            return '';
        } else {
            $dataArray = GFFormsModel::unserialize($value);
            $arrayCount = count($dataArray);
            $output = "\n";
            $count = 0;
            $repeatCount = 0;
            $display_empty_fields = rgget('gf_display_empty_fields', $_COOKIE);
            $form_id = $this->formId;
            $get_form = GFFormsModel::get_form_meta_by_id($form_id);
            $form = $get_form[0];

            foreach ($dataArray as $key=>$value) {
                $repeatCount++;
                $tableContents = '';

                if (!empty($value) && !is_array($value)) {
                    $save_value = $value;
                    unset($value);
                    $value[0] = $save_value;
                }

                foreach ($value as $childKey=>$childValue) {
                    $count++;
                    $childValueOutput = '';

                    if (empty($display_empty_fields) && count($childValue) == 0) { continue; }

                    if (is_numeric($childKey)) {
                        $field_index = GF_Field_Repeater::get_field_index($form, 'id', $childKey);
                        if ($field_index === false) { continue; }
                        $entry_title = $form['fields'][$field_index]['label'];
                    } else {
                        $entry_title = $childKey;
                    }

                    $entry_title = str_replace('[gfRepeater-count]', $repeatCount, $entry_title);

                    if ($format == 'html') {
                        if ($childValue == '[gfRepeater-section]') {
                            if ($media == 'email') {
                                $tableStyling = ' style="font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#eee;border-bottom:1px solid #dfdfdf;padding:7px 7px"';
                            } else {
                                $tableStyling = ' class="entry-view-section-break"';
                            }
                        } else {
                            if ($media == 'email') {
                                $tableStyling = ' style="background-color:#EAF2FA;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold"';
                            } else {
                                $tableStyling = ' class="entry-view-field-name"';
                            }
                        }

                        $tableContents .= "<tr>\n<td colspan=\"2\"".$tableStyling.">".$entry_title."</td>\n</tr>\n";
                    } else {
                        $tableContents .= $entry_title.": ";
                    }

                    if (is_array($childValue)) {
                        if (count($childValue) == 1) {
                            $childValueOutput = $childValue[0];
                        } elseif (count($childValue) > 1) {
                            if ($format == 'html') {
                                if ($media == 'email') {
                                    $childValueOutput = "<ul style=\"list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;\">\n";
                                } else {
                                    $childValueOutput = "<ul>\n";
                                }
                            }

                            foreach ($childValue as $childValueData) {
                                if ($format == 'html') {
                                    $childValueOutput .= "<li>".$childValueData."</li>";
                                } else {
                                    $childValueOutput .= $childValueData."\n";
                                }
                            }

                            if ($format == 'html') { $childValueOutput .= "</ul>\n"; }
                        }

                        if ($media == 'email') { $tableStyling = ''; } else { $tableStyling = ' class=\"entry-view-field-value\"'; }

                        if ($format == 'html') {
                            $tableContents .= "<tr>\n<td colspan=\"2\"".$tableStyling.">".$childValueOutput."</td>\n</tr>\n";
                        } else {
                            $tableContents .= $childValueOutput."\n";
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (!empty($tableContents)) {
                    if ($format == 'html') {
                        if ($media == 'email') { $tableStyling = ' width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"'; } else { $tableStyling = ' class="widefat fixed entry-detail-view"'; }
                        $output .= "<table cellspacing=\"0\"".$tableStyling.">\n";
                        $output .= $tableContents;
                        $output .= "</table>\n";
                    } else {
                        $output .= $tableContents."\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ($count !== 0) {
            if ($format == 'text') { $output = rtrim($output); }
            return $output;
        } else { return ''; }
    }

    public function get_value_merge_tag($value, $input_id, $entry, $form, $modifier, $raw_value, $url_encode, $esc_html, $format, $nl2br) {
        $output = GF_Field_Repeater::get_value_entry_detail($raw_value, '', false, $format, 'email');
        $output = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $output);
        return trim($output);
    }

    public function get_value_export($entry, $input_id = '', $use_text = false, $is_csv = false) {
        if (empty($input_id)) { $input_id = $this->id; }
        $output = rgar($entry, $input_id);
        $output = GF_Field_Repeater::get_value_entry_detail($output, '', false, 'text', 'email');
        $output = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", ", ", trim($output));
        return $output;
    }

    public static function gform_hide_children($form) {
        $form_id = $form['id'];
        $repeaterChildren = Array();
        $grid_modified = false;
        $grid_meta = GFFormsModel::get_grid_column_meta($form_id);

        foreach($form['fields'] as $key=>$field) {
            if ($field->type == 'repeater') {
                if (is_array($field->repeaterChildren)) { $repeaterChildren = array_merge($repeaterChildren, $field->repeaterChildren); }
            } elseif ($field->type == 'repeater-end') { array_push($repeaterChildren, $field->id); }

            if (!empty($repeaterChildren)) {
                if (in_array($field->id, $repeaterChildren)) {
                    unset($form['fields'][$key]);

                    if (is_array($grid_meta)) {
                        $grid_pos = array_search($field->id, $grid_meta);
                        if ($grid_pos) {
                            $grid_modified = true;
                            unset($grid_meta[$grid_pos]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ($grid_modified) { GFFormsModel::update_grid_column_meta($form_id, $grid_meta); }

        $form['fields'] = array_values($form['fields']);

        return $form;
    }

    public static function gform_disable_ajax($args) {
        $get_form = GFFormsModel::get_form_meta_by_id($args['form_id']);
        $form = reset($get_form);

        if (GF_Field_Repeater::get_field_index($form) !== false) {
            $args['ajax'] = false;
        }

        return $args;
    }

    public static function gform_bypass_children_validation($form) {
        if (GF_Field_Repeater::get_field_index($form) === false) { return $form; }

        $repeaterChildren = Array();

        foreach($form['fields'] as $key=>$field) {
            if ($field->type == 'repeater') {
                if (is_array($field->repeaterChildren)) { $repeaterChildren = array_merge($repeaterChildren, $field->repeaterChildren); }
            }

            if (!empty($repeaterChildren)) {
                if (in_array($field->id, $repeaterChildren) && !$field->adminOnly) {
                    $form['fields'][$key]['adminOnly'] = true;
                    $form['fields'][$key]['repeaterChildValidationHidden'] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return $form;
    }

    public static function gform_unhide_children_validation($form) {
        if (GF_Field_Repeater::get_field_index($form) === false) { return $form; }

        foreach($form['fields'] as $key=>$field) {
            if ($field->repeaterChildValidationHidden) {
                $form['fields'][$key]['adminOnly'] = false;
                $form['fields'][$key]['repeaterChildValidationHidden'] = false;
            }
        }

        return $form;
    }

    public static function get_field_index($form, $key = 'type', $value = 'repeater') {
        if (is_array($form)) {
            if (!array_key_exists('fields', $form)) { return false; }
        } else { return false; }

        foreach ($form['fields'] as $field_key=>$field_value) {
            if (is_object($field_value)) {
                if (property_exists($field_value, $key)) {
                    if ($field_value[$key] == $value) { return $field_key; }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static function get_field_type($form, $id) {
        $field_index = GF_Field_Repeater::get_field_index($form, 'id', $id);
        if ($field_index !== false) { return $form['fields'][$field_index]['type']; }
        return false;
    }

    public static function get_children_parems($form, $children_ids) {
        foreach($form['fields'] as $key=>$value) {
            if (in_array($value['id'], $children_ids)) {
                if ($value['inputName']) {
                    $parems[$value['id']] = $value['inputName'];
                } elseif ($value['inputs']) {
                    foreach($value['inputs'] as $key=>$value) {
                        if ($value['name']) { $parems[$value['id']] = $value['name']; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($parems)) { return $parems; } else { return false; }
    }

    public static function get_children_parem_values($form, $children_ids) {
        global $wp_filter;
        $children_parems = GF_Field_Repeater::get_children_parems($form, $children_ids);

        if (empty($children_parems)) { return false; }

        // Check the URL first
        foreach($_GET as $url_key=>$url_value) {
            $key = array_search($url_key, $children_parems);
            if ($key !== false) {
                $parems[$key][0] = $url_value;
            } else {
                $split_key = preg_split('/\D+\K/', $url_key);
                $key = array_search($split_key[0], $children_parems);
                if ($key !== false) { $parems[$key][$split_key[1]] = $url_value; }
            }
        }

        // Then check the filters
        foreach($wp_filter as $key=>$value) {
            $split_key = preg_split('/^gform_field_value_+\K/', $key);
            if (!empty($split_key[1])) {
                $key1 = array_search($split_key[1], $children_parems);
                if ($key1 !== false) {
                    $parems[$key1][0] = apply_filters($key, '');
                } else {
                    $split_key2 = preg_split('/\D+\K/', $split_key[1]);
                    $key2 = array_search($split_key2[0], $children_parems);
                    if ($key2 !== false) { $parems[$key2][$split_key2[1]] = apply_filters($key, ''); }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($parems)) { return $parems; } else { return false; }
    }
}
GF_Fields::register(new GF_Field_Repeater());
```